# Restful Web Services api documentation tool

Tags: api, web-services, software-testing, user-interface, documentation-generator

Before during, and even after Web Services implementation, an up-to-date user guide is very important to our customers. I am trying to find an API tool for Restful Web Services which can produce a user-friendly document / user guide in either WORD or PDF format. Is there any suggestions?

Key points include:

- Documenting APIs
- Basic information on API (current user guide)
- How to use APIs
- Test APIs before implementation

Comment: Consider http://swagger.io

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [apidocjs](http://apidocjs.com/) ?

- **Documenting APIs**

  Well, it quite easy, because what we need to do is just commenting on our code. This is an example.

  > ```
  > /**
  >  * @api {get} /user/:id Request User information
  >  * @apiName GetUser
  >  * @apiGroup User
  >  *
  >  * @apiParam {Number} id Users unique ID.
  >  *
  >  * @apiSuccess {String} firstname Firstname of the User.
  >  * @apiSuccess {String} lastname  Lastname of the User.
  >  */
  > ```

  Example on [Lumen Framework](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.2/controllers), you can put the comment on Controllers `app/Http/Controllers/UserController@create`. `@` refer to function inside the controller.

  Use this command to generate the doc

  > apidoc -i app/Http/Controllers -o public/docs
- **Basic information on API (current user guide)**

  Yes, please go to [apidocjs example](http://apidocjs.com/example/).
- **How to use APIs**

  See above example.
- **Test APIs before implementation**

  It has an interesting feature, check `@apiSampleRequest`. But if you mean Test is Unit Testing or Functional Testing, apidocjs not support.